# Hiding WebKit scrollbar when overflow-scrolling: touch is enabled

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, webkit, mobile-safari

As we all know, you can hide a scrollbar in Safari and Chromium with the following CSS snippet:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to work when `-webkit-overflow-scrolling` is set to `touch`, specifically on iOS. Chromium properly hides the scrollbar.

Is this a WebKit bug, or is there a way to hide a scrollbar AND enable fluid (touch) scrolling? It seems to be possible (perhaps with js?), on the mobile version of [Google](https://www.google.com/#q=test). Looking through the page source and googling my answer didn't seem to help though.

Comment: Support Level is Under development. That is what apple says: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html#//apple_ref/css/property/-webkit-overflow-scrolling

There can be some hack for it.

Comment: Thanks. I'll find another method.

Answer (score 7):

It seems that currently (as of January 2017) the only way to get around this is by wrapping the scrollable element inside of a parent div and manually hiding the scrollbar from view.

This can be achieved by applying a fixed height/width and `overflow: hidden;` to the parent div. You can then add extra padding or height/width to the original element to, essentially, push the scrollbar out of view.

[Mark Otto](https://twitter.com/mdo) [tweeted about the issue](https://twitter.com/mdo/status/738791217719189504) back in June 2016. Here is an example of his workaround: https://output.jsbin.com/lohiga.

The basic idea goes something like this:

```
<header>
  <div> <!-- parent wrapper added -->
    <nav>
      <a href="#">First link</a>
      <a href="#">Link</a>
      <a href="#">Link</a>
      <a href="#">Link</a>
      <a href="#">Link</a>
      <a href="#">Link</a>
      <a href="#">Link</a>
      <a href="#">Link</a>
      <a href="#">Last link</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
header {
  margin: 20px 0;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

// Parent wrapper
div {
  height: 30px;
  overflow-y: hidden; // "crop" the view so the scrollbar can't be seen
}

// Original scrollable element
nav {
  padding-bottom: 20px; // extra padding to push the scrollbar out of view
  overflow-x: auto;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the long response delay -- I don't ask questions here very often.